# How to not abort jobs that are already aborted?

Tags: apex, scheduled-job, asyncapexjob, cron

I have a function that gets called as part of reschedule logic in a Shedulable Apex class that implements System.Schedulable. The following code only gets called when a reschedule is needed. Rather then just pass a job ID into System.abortJob() in the code below, I would like to see if the job had already been aborted. However [CronTrigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) only gives statuses of  COMPLETE, ERROR, DELETED, PAUSED, BLOCKED, or PAUSED_BLOCKED.
Do I need to query AsyncApexJob since that does carry the status of 'aborted' ? That is I am not clear on the correlation between the two classes.

```
@TestVisible private void rescheduleJob(CronTrigger me, ISchedulable item, MySchedulableContext myCtx) {
        try {
            System.abortJob(me.Id);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('Unable to abort the job');
        }
        String newTrigger = item.getNextTriggerString(myCtx);
        if (newTrigger != null && newTrigger.length() > 0) {
            try {
                System.schedule(me.CronJobDetail.Name+ '-' + System.currentTimeMillis(), newTrigger, this);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug('Unable to start the job');
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Salesforce documentation

AsyncApexJob Represents an individual Apex sharing recalculation job, a batch
Apex job, a method with the future annotation, or a job that
implements Queueable.

CronTrigger Contains schedule information for a scheduled job. CronTrigger is
similar to a cron job on UNIX systems.

So basically, AsyncApexJob shows what's already run and CronTrigger shows what's coming up in future.

I had a similar requirement so I query AsyncApexJob  to test the last run job status based on ApexClassName.

```
List<AsyncApexJob> apexJobStatus=[SELECT Id,Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ApexClass.Name=:ApexClassName ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
```